# How do I copy data if cell contains text?

Tags: google-sheets

[image: screen shot of Google Sheet]

Basically, I have a book which gets data anytime someone fills a form.

There are five groups I need the data divided into.

If a cell contains one of the five answers all the answers by user need to be copied in its respective sheet.

I have tried using nested if statements but it gets too complex too quickly.

```
=IF(D2 ="Squeaky clean",IF(E2="Just once","Normal"),IF(D2="A little tingly. Sometimes it stings",IF(E2="Just once","Sensitive")),IF(D2="A little tight all over",IF(E2="Just once","Normal")),IF(D2="Tight across my forehead but otherwise it feels pretty good",IF(E2="Just once","Combination")))
```

Here's what I have tried using.

This data then goes to Mailchimp lists which triggers emails when the list is updated.

Answer (score 1):

I tried asking the same question on Google Product Forums and someone posted this script. It works like a charm. Hope you guys find it useful.

```
    /**
 * Moves row of data to another spreadsheet based on criteria in column 6 to sheet with same name as the value in column 3.
*/

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.range;

  // to let you modify where the action and move columns are in the form responses sheet
  var actionCol = 6;
  var nameCol = 3;

  // Get the row and column of the active cell.
  var rowIndex = r.getRowIndex();
  var colIndex = r.getColumnIndex();

  // Get the number of columns in the active sheet.
  // -1 to drop our action/status column
  var colNumber = s.getLastColumn()-1;

  // if the action/status col is changed to ok do stuff. Change "ok" below to whatever you want the trigger word to be.
  if (e.value == "ok" && colIndex == actionCol) {
    // get our target sheet name - in this example we are using the Skin Type column
    var targetSheet = s.getRange(rowIndex, nameCol).getValue();
    // if the sheet exists do more stuff
    if (ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet)) { 
      // set our target sheet and target range
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet);
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, colNumber);
      // get our source range/row
      var sourceRange = s.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, colNumber);
      // new sheets says: 'Cannot cut from form data. Use copy instead.' 
      sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
      // ..but we can still delete the row after.  Put // in front of below row if you don't want to delete after copying to new sheet
      s.deleteRow(rowIndex);
      // or remove // below if you want to keep but note the move, but you'll need to add // to row above if removing // from below
      //  r.setValue("Copied");
    }
  }
}
```